# I am trying to convert C code to Mathematica code, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c, wolfram-mathematica

I am new to Mathematica and it seems i am missing something in Mathematica syntax.

I copied both codes below.

Print[second] must return 120 for this example but it is always 0.

Any advice is appreciated.

C:

```
    int row = 4;
    int column = 10;
    int passenger = 5;
    int luggage = 20;
    int arrival = 15;
    int walking = 5;

    int second = 0;
    int waitingtime = 0;
    int _yolcu = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <row; i++)
        {
          waitingtime = 0;
          if (_yolcu == passenger)
              break;
          for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
          { 
              if (_yolcu == passenger)
                  break;
              _yolcu++;
              if (i == 0 && j == 0){
                  second = second + luggage;
                  continue;
                      }

              else
                      {
                  waitingtime = 0;
                  waitingtime =second-(j * walking + arrival * (_yolcu - 1));
                  if (waitingtime>= 0)
                  {
                      second = second + walking + luggage;
                  }
                  else        
                      second = second -  waitingtime+luggage;
              }

          }
      }
```

Mathematica:

```
        row = 4;
        column = 10;
        passenger = 5;
        luggage = 20;
        arrival = 15;
        walking = 5;

        second = 0;
        waitingtime = 0;
        _yolcu = 0;

        For[i = 0, i < row, i++, waitingtime = 0;
         If[_yolcu == passenger, Break[],
          For[j = 0, j < column, j++,
           If[_yolcu == passenger, Break[], _yolcu++;
            If[i == 0 && j == 0, second = second + luggage, 
             waitingtime = second - (j*walking + arrival*(_yolcu - 1));
             If[waitingtime >= 0, second = second + walking + luggage, 
              second = second - waitingtime + luggage]]]]]]

        Print[second]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

`_yolcu`

isn't a valid Mathematica symbol name so the expression `_yolcu = 5` doesn't cause Mathematica to put a variable called `_yolcu` with value `5` into the context symbol table.  Try executing the statement interactively, then try executing `_yolcu` again; Mathematica will (or rather does for me) return `_yolcu` not `5`.

In fact `_yolcu` is a *pattern* which matches things with `Head` `yolcu`.  Generally any expression starting with an underscore is a pattern; underscores are not valid in names of Mathematica symbols.  An expression such as `_yolcu++` doesn't increment the value of `_yolcu`.  I don't actually know what it does, other than produce an error when I execute the statement; perhaps your code doesn't actually ever hit it.

If you don't yet understand Mathematica patterns I suggest you review the documentation.

And, while I'm writing, what you have done looks subtly different from translating a C code into Mathematica, it looks much more as if you have translated a C code to 'C-written-in-Mathematica`.  I think that your time would be better spent reverse engineering the C to a problem specification and then coding a Mathematica solution to the problem.  I think that this is your basic mistake, the confusion over underscores is just unfamiliarity with Mathematica's syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot , that underscore was causing me the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you got it working, but in reference to HPMark's last paragraph, the performance of iterative loops in Mathematica is dismal. To write good Mathemaitca expressions, you need to think in terms of applying a function to list(s) in a way that achieves the same thing. Kind of like the list is an un-rolled Do loop, and iteration is, in effect, achieved by traversing this list.